# Animated UIImageViews within an infinite sideways UIScrollView in Swift - is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a very simple app in Swift for iOS.

Essentially, it's an infinitely (sideways) scrolling fishtank. Users swipe/scroll either right or left, and see illustrated fish.

Ok, so, the app starts with three 'tiles', each of which contains a random number of fish, with the UIScrollView centered on the middle tile. The fish are simple UIImageViews containing a PNG which themselves each have a small animation to move them x pixels independently of everything else and then stop.

If a user scrolls right and reaches a certain point, the tile to the far left is removed and a new tile to the right is added.

Similarly, if a user scrolls left and reaches a certain point, the tile to the far right is removed and a new tile to the left is added.

Once we have a new tile at either side, we recenter the scrollview and everything else, and the whole process starts again.

It all works fine and I'm fairly happy with the mechanics of it all.

However, my problem is when recentering happens - if we're scrolling at the time (which we most likely are), the recentering causes a very visible skip or jump, rather than it being a super smooth transition which is what I'd like.

I'm virtually 100% sure that this is due to the number of animated fish/UIImages contained within each tile, because if I bring the number of fish within a tile down to a relatively small number (like 5 per tile), there is no scrolling/recentering stutter... but then there aren't enough fish on screen. Ideally, I'd like between 40 and 50 per tile.

So, my question is, is there a better or more efficient way to present the fish than as UIImageViews (as subviews of a tile)?

My device can run some pretty high end games, so I'm sure it must be able to handle something like this with ease - which means there must be a waaay better way of doing it than what I'm doing right now.

For reference, the my Tile() UIView is:

```
class Tile: UIView {

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }



    func bringOnTheFish() {

        var i = 1
        while i < randInRange(numberOfFishMin...numberOfFishMax) {
            self.addSubview(Fish())
            i++
        }

    }


}
```

And my Fish() UIImageView is:

```
class Fish: UIImageView {


    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        self.spawn()
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
        self.spawn()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.spawn()
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    func spawn() {

        //Random fish size
        let fishSizeX = randInRange(minFishSize...maxFishSize)
        let fishSizeY = randInRange(minFishSize...(maxFishSize/2))

        //Random position & prevent placement at edge of tile
        let fishPositionX = randInRange((fishSizeX)...(Int(tileWidth) - fishSizeX))
        let fishPositionY = randInRange((fishSizeY + skyHeight)...(Int(tileHeight) - fishSizeY - skyHeight))
        self.frame = CGRect(x: fishPositionX,   y: fishPositionY,    width: fishSizeX, height: fishSizeY)

        //Random fish image
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayOfFish.count)))
        self.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfFish[randomIndex]);
        self.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        //Swim to random position
        var swimToPositionX = fishPositionX + randInRange(swimDistanceXMin...swimDistanceXMax)
        let swimToPositionY = fishPositionY + randInRange(swimDistanceYMin...swimDistanceYMax)

        //Random direction (left or right - images naturally face right)
        let direction = randInRange(1...2)
        if direction == 1 {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
            swimToPositionX = fishPositionX - randInRange(swimDistanceXMin...swimDistanceXMax)
        }

        let swimTime = randInRange(swimTimeMin...swimTimeMax)

        //Animate
        UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(swimTime), animations: { ()-> Void in
            self.frame = CGRect(x: swimToPositionX, y: swimToPositionY, width: fishSizeX, height: fishSizeY)
            return
        })


    }


}
```

Thanks! :o)

Comment: Have you considered sprite kit instead of UIView?

Comment: I had been thinking about it, but not gotten round to actually trying to use it. Will that make a difference, do you think?